# How can I use post method data in back end to save many to many relationship data with @JsonIgnore annotation.My joining table is not updating

Tags: json, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, many-to-many

How can I use the data send through post method, and save those data in a many to many relationship? I used @JsonIgnore annotation to stop the recursion.

I have implemented two entities.One is Employee and the other is Skills.In the Employee entity I used @JsonIgnore annotation to avoid the reccursion. But when I inserted the values Employee table got updated but the joining tabled is not updating.

This is my Employee entity class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Employee")
public class Employee implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3009157732242241606L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long emp_id;

    @Column(name = "emp_fname")
    private String emp_fname;

    @Column(name = "emp_lname")
    private String emp_lname;

    @Column(name = "emp_email")
    private String emp_email;

    @Column(name = "emp_dob")
    private Date emp_dob;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    @JoinTable(name = "emp_skills",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "emp_id", referencedColumnName = "emp_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "s_id",referencedColumnName = "s_id"))
    @JsonIgnore
    private Set<Skills> skills;
}
```

This is my Skills class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Skills")
public class Skills implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3009157732242241606L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long s_id;

    @Column(name = "s_name")
    private String s_name;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "skills")
    private Set<Employee> employees;
```

And this is my controller class method to save data

```
@RequestMapping("/save")
        @PostMapping("/save")
        @CrossOrigin
        public void createEmployee(@RequestBody Employee employee, BindingResult bindingResult){
        Employee emp = new Employee(employee.getEmp_fname(),employee.getEmp_lname(),employee.getEmp_email(),employee.getEmp_dob());

        emp.setSkills(employee.getSkills());

        empRepository.save(emp);
        //empRepository.save(new Employee(employee.getEmp_fname(),employee.getEmp_lname(),employee.getEmp_email(),employee.getEmp_dob()));
        }
```

I want to update both Employee and emp_skills (the joining table) when the save method is triggered.

Comment: It doesn't make sence to me.But when I put the @Jsonignore to skills  entity my problem saved.Any idea what happened??

Comment: Try to use `cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.MERGE},` on `private Set<Employee> employees;`

Comment: Thanks for the reply.After including the @Jsonignore in skills entity both tables getting update.